# Find String that starts with in array AS3

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, indexof

I want to prevent users from using webcam emulators, I have done that in **AS2** by using senocular's function, but I can't make it work in AS3,so, here is the [old version by senocular](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_1.0/Prototypes/String/startsWith.as) , and I would like to do the same in **AS3**, tried using **indexOf** but doesn't work, I need to find at least the first 4 characters of the string and compare them to the item inside the array in AS3!

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
        return !this.indexOf(str);
    }
```

**here is what I want to do:**

```
var bannedDevices = new Array("FakeCam","SplitCam","Phillips Capture Card 7xx","VLC");

var myDeviceName = "SplitCam v1.5";  //"Splitcam" in bannedDevices should trigger this;

if (myDeviceName.indexOf(bannedDevices)){
   trace("banned device");
}
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I leave my previous answer for history. Now that i've understood what you want:

```
public function FlashTest() {
    var bannedDevices:Array = new Array("FakeCam","SplitCam","Phillips Capture Card 7xx","VLC");

    var myDeviceName:String = "SplitCam v1.5";  //"Splitcam" in bannedDevices should trigger this;

    trace(startsWith(myDeviceName, bannedDevices, 4));
}

/**
* @returns An array of strings in pHayStack beginning with pLength first characters of pNeedle
*/
private function startsWith(pNeedle:String, pHayStack:Array, pLength:uint):Array
{
    var result:Array = [];
    for each (var hay:String in pHayStack)
    {
        if (hay.match("^"+pNeedle.substr(0,pLength)))
        {
            result.push(hay);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need is not very clear... Here is a function which returns every string from an array that starts with the given string.

```
public function FlashTest() {
    var hayStack:Array = ["not this one", "still not this one", "ok this one is good", "a trap ok", "okgood too"];

    trace(startsWith("ok", hayStack));
}

/**
* @returns An array of strings in pHayStack beginning with the given string
*/
private function startsWith(pNeedle:String, pHayStack:Array):Array
{
    var result:Array = [];
    for each (var hay:String in pHayStack)
    {
        if (hay.match("^"+pNeedle))
        {
            result.push(hay);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hello Kodiak, thanks for the reply, but it does not work as I need it to, if i add something to "ok" like: "ok v2.4" then it won't trace anything.

Comment: You need to define what you need more precisely, here my function returns the strings which starts with EXACTLY the given param...